# Retrieve bridge's IP within docker container or provide via environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-network

When I create a docker network, a bridge is added:

```
docker network create DUMMY
```

Now executing `ifconfig` gives:

```
br-8a429249b4d9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.255.136.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.255.136.255
        inet6 fe80::42:88ff:fe9b:9a33  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:88:9b:9a:33  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9  bytes 388 (388.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 74  bytes 11136 (11.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Is it possible to retrieve that IP `10.255.136.1` from a container running inside the `DUMMY` network?

I am dockerizing an application which requires the source IP (which, in this case, is another application running on the host) to be whitelisted in some configuration file and I believe that should be the bridge's IP. Hence my question to retrieve that IP from within the actual container. Or alternatively, is there a way to provide that IP to the container via an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip address of the bridge will be the default gateway inside the container. In other words, you can just parse the output from e.g. `ip route` to find the bridge address.

For example, if I create a DUMMY network, I get:

```
6: br-ea7804d337bc: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:8e:97:b4:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-ea7804d337bc
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:8eff:fe97:b402/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I start a container on that network:

```
docker run -it --rm --net DUMMY alpine sh
```

I have the following routing table:

```
/ # ip route
default via 172.20.0.1 dev eth0
172.20.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.20.0.2
```

And I can get the ip address itself by running that output through `awk`:

```
/ # ip route | awk '$1 == "default" {print $3}'
172.20.0.1
```